# Disable Kubernetes pod update when container digest is same even if different image tag is given

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment

Let's say I have an image `foo` with tag `v1`.
So I deployed it on Kubernetes by `foo:v1`.

However, for some reason(e.g. monoversion in monorepo), I pushed the exact same image to container registry with tag `v2`.
And I changed k8s manifest to `foo:v2`.

In this situation, I want to update the pod only when the `image digest` of `v1` and `v2` are different. So in the case of foo, the digest are same, so container of `foo:v1` should keep running.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to update `tag` image without restarting pod. 
The only way to make it work is too use `digest` explicitly instead of tags.

So now image spec would look like this:

```
spec:
  image: foo@sha256:50cf965a6e08ec5784009d0fccb380fc479826b6e0e65684d9879170a9df8566
```

This way your image does not depended on tags. Digests can be found either on `dockerhub` or by running command `docker images --digests <image-name>`

Comment: Thanks! 
[@cppforlife_](https://www.reddit.com/user/cppforlife_/) in Reddit([post link](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/ekqszk/disable_kubernetes_pod_update_when_container/)) suggested `get-kbld.io` as well to automatically resolve tag to digest when deploying. (Haven't tried it, though)